# How to avoid casting on inherited recursive class with wildcard?

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, polymorphism

1) Suppose you have the following abstract class definition:

```
abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<T> {
    AbstractBinaryTree<T> parent;
    AbstractBinaryTree<T> leftChild;
    AbstractBinaryTree<T> rightChild;
    T value;     
}
```

and an implementation of this class with a new method not previously declared or implemented:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractBinaryTree<T> {
    public BinarySearchTree(T pVal) {
        super(pVal);
    }


    public Boolean isBST(){
    if(leftChild != null && rightChild != null){
        return (leftChild.value.compareTo(value) < 0 
                && rightChild.value.compareTo(value) >= 0 )
                && ((BinarySearchTree<T>) leftChild).isBST() 
                && ((BinarySearchTree<T>) rightChild).isBST();
    }
    else if(leftChild != null){
        return leftChild.value.compareTo(value) < 0 
                && ((BinarySearchTree<T>) leftChild).isBST() ;
    }
    else if (rightChild != null){
        return rightChild.value.compareTo(value) >= 0
        && ((BinarySearchTree<T>) rightChild).isBST();
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

How do you avoid having to cast all left and right children?

2) Similarly suppose i had the following abstract definition in AbstractBinaryTree:

```
    public abstract AbstractBinaryTree<T> findMinTree();
```

and its implementation in BST:

```
/***
 * @return the subtree rooted at the min value
 */
public BinarySearchTree<T> findMinTree(){
    if(leftChild != null)
        return (BinarySearchTree<T>) leftChild.findMinTree();
    return this;
}
```

How do I avoid the cast in

```
public BinarySearchTree<T> findMinTree(){
    if(leftChild != null)
        return (BinarySearchTree<T>) leftChild.findMinTree();
    return this;
}
```

or when i call it on a child?

```
BinarySearchTree<T> y = ((BinarySearchTree<T>) x.rightChild).findMinTree();
```

I am not allergic to casting but its very heavy in this case.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: As a totally tangential comment, you'll want to return a `boolean` instead of `Boolean` in your `isBST()` method - as is, it's autoboxing your return value into a `Boolean` object, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use even more generics, namely the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<T, TTree extends AbstractBinaryTree<T, TTree>> {
    TTree parent;
    TTree leftChild;
    TTree rightChild;
    T value;     
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'd never seen the reference to CRTP before, I was wondering if it had a name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the class having the abstract superclass refer to a reference of itself for the structure of the tree, I would have it use a `Node` class that has references to its parent `Node`, and left and right children `Nodes`.  The `AbstractBinaryTree` class would have a reference to the root `Node`.

```
abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<T> {
    Node<T> root;
    static class Node<E>
    {
        Node<E> parent;
        Node<E> leftChild;
        Node<E> rightChild;
        E value;
    }
}
```

Then subclasses wouldn't need the type of the `Node` to vary with its own type; `BinarySearchTree` would also use `Node`s.

```
class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractBinaryTree<T>
{
    // No need to redefine the structure types here.
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply. I knew I could implement trees like that but my question was more generally for recursive classes.